# Basic elasticsearch tribe setup with docker

Tags: elasticsearch, docker

I am wanting to do a very basic setup to see if a tribe setup works with docker. I have the below:

A 1 node cluster that I run with simply:

```
docker run -d elasticsearch
```

I then check the IP of the above container with docker inspect.
I then run another elasticsearch container with the below config so that it can connect to the above.

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0

tribe:
    c1:
        cluster.name: cluster1
        discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.17.0.2"]
```

Note that '172.17.0.2' is the IP of the first container. When I run this though, I see the below exceptions at startup and it crashes:

```
[2016-12-24T17:43:14,956][WARN ][o.e.d.z.UnicastZenPing   ] [Y8QThsS/c1] [1] failed send ping to {#zen_unicast_1#}{CUKFEuPTT4CFGz5ok-7gqw}{172.17.0.2}{172.17.0.2:9300}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: handshake failed, mismatched cluster name [Cluster [elasticsearch]] - {#zen_unicast_1#}{CUKFEuPTT4CFGz5ok-7gqw}{172.17.0.2}{172.17.0.2:9300}
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.handshake(TransportService.java:374) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNodeLightAndHandshake(TransportService.java:345) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNodeLightAndHandshake(TransportService.java:319) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.UnicastZenPing$2.run(UnicastZenPing.java:473) [elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:458) [elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
[2016-12-24T17:43:17,054][WARN ][o.e.d.z.UnicastZenPing   ] [Y8QThsS/c1] [1] failed send ping to {#zen_unicast_1#}{CUKFEuPTT4CFGz5ok-7gqw}{172.17.0.2}{172.17.0.2:9300}
java.lang.IllegalStateException: handshake failed, mismatched cluster name [Cluster [elasticsearch]] - {#zen_unicast_1#}{CUKFEuPTT4CFGz5ok-7gqw}{172.17.0.2}{172.17.0.2:9300}
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.handshake(TransportService.java:374) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNodeLightAndHandshake(TransportService.java:345) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportService.connectToNodeLightAndHandshake(TransportService.java:319) ~[elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.discovery.zen.UnicastZenPing$2.run(UnicastZenPing.java:473) [elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at org.elasticsearch.common.util.concurrent.ThreadContext$ContextPreservingRunnable.run(ThreadContext.java:458) [elasticsearch-5.1.1.jar:5.1.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [?:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_111]
```

I appreciate any help and let me know if I should clarify anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! It says it right in the logs (doh!). Had to match the cluster name in the tribe config with what was set (or assumed as default) in the cluster.

```
network.host: 0.0.0.0

tribe:
    c1:
        cluster.name: elasticsearch
        discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["172.17.0.2"]
```